# Send request to the url if string found

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to work on a website and the code works fine, but sometimes the response text has a specific string `error happened`. If that string appears, I need to send request to that item again
Here's my try but I still got some results with that string `error happened`

```
for item in mylist:
    while True:
        response = requests.get(f'myurl/{item}', headers=headers)
        res_text = response.text

        if 'SUCESSFUL EXECUTION' in res_text:
            scraped_item = (item, 'PAY IT')
        else:
            json_data=json.loads(res_text)
            scraped_item = (item, json_data['errorMsg'])

        print(scraped_item)
        results.append(scraped_item)
        if not 'error happened' in res_text:break
```

Answer (score 0):

I could solve it using `while True` trick

```
for item in mylist:
    while True:
        response = requests.get(f'myurl/{item}', headers=headers)
        res_text = response.text
        if not 'error happened' in res_text:
            break

    if 'SUCESSFUL EXECUTION' in res_text:
        scraped_item = (item, 'PAY IT')
    else:
        json_data=json.loads(res_text)
        scraped_item = (item, json_data['errorMsg'])

    print(scraped_item)
    results.append(scraped_item)
    time.sleep(1)
```